# NoViableAltException using jpa

Tags: java, jpa, wicket, eclipselink

i´ve got a problem to get jpa running. Following exception appears when i try to run the Login.java

> WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public de.test.pages.LoginPage()
>
> Root cause:
>
> NoViableAltException(93!=[364:1: selectExpression returns [Object node] : (n= aggregateExpression | n= scalarExpression | OBJECT LEFT_ROUND_BRACKET n= variableAccessOrTypeConstant RIGHT_ROUND_BRACKET | n= constructorExpression | n= mapEntryExpression );])
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectExpression(JPQLParser.java:5893)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectItem(JPQLParser.java:1356)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectClause(JPQLParser.java:1270)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:351)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:275)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:130)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:91)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:207)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:182)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:134)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:118)
>   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1352)
>   at de.test.pages.LoginPage.(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>   at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
>   at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
>   at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>   at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>   at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>   at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>   at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
>   at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)

The method LoginPage() in Login.java looks like this:

public LoginPage() {

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("quickstartUser");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    // Read the existing entries
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM quickstart_user");
    // Persons should be empty

    // Do we have entries?
    int createNewEntries = q.getResultList().size();

    Label label = new Label("result", "Result: ");
    add(label);

    // It is always good practice to close the EntityManager so that
    // resources are conserved.
    em.close();
```

The persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="quickstartUser" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test" />
        <!-- I work in this example without user / password.-->
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="" />

        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Although the table should be created automatically, i had to create the table on myself.

At least the entity model QuickstartUser.java

@Entity
public class QuickstartUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    private String username;

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

Thank you for reading.

BVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently studying JPA, but I usually write a query like

SELECT * FROM quickstart_user

as

SELECT q FROM quickstart_user q

Can you try to change your code and see if this will work?
As a side note, I also found that, for some of my projects, the Hibernate JPA implementation works better than the Eclipse one.

Comment: Hi, i got a result and the exception is gone. What is the idea about using the query like you did?

Comment: The syntax of the JPA Query Language is similar to SQL, but it implements only a subset of it. 
The EntityManager provides the createNativeQuery and createNamedQuery that allow SQL queries, while createQuery supports JQL only.

Comment: This is a terrible exception message and I have filed a bug ( https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323038 ) to have it changed changed.  Please vote for the bug if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the answer to your problem, but:

You should never call database code from inside a front end component, this is a terrible mix of model and view.

You should create a service to access your database (using JPA or whatever) and inject this service into either your page (using component instantiation listeners with wicket-spring or wicket-guice) or your wicket application.

That way you can test each layer in isolation